# Mitsubishi Galant over heating with battery light and brake light on

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, galant

I have a 2000 Mitsubishi Galant ES 2.4 cylinder engine. I parked my car after leaving the laundry mart and I got in to pick up my children and it would crank but won't start. So we changed the spark plugs, wires, ingnition coils, a new battery. Before the battery after we did the wires and coils and plugs it still would get a spark. So I checked the fuse box under the hood and the yellow number 20 was burnt so replaced it and it started right up. When that happened the brake light, battery light came on and my thermometer went by the red line. As I stopped and go it went up and down but never over over heated. Even after we replaced the battery. What could this be?

Comment: What did the 20A fuse actually go to? (20 on a yellow blade fuse indicates the amperage of the fuse.)  Seems a bit strong for the ignition. The info for what it is should be on the back of the fuse panel cover. Also, was it the engine temp gauge which was going up and down? Wondering why you replaced the battery?

Comment: Also, have you checked your alternator for proper function?

Comment: We need more details here.  Could be lots of things.  Did you check your coolant/water level in the radiator?  How old is the thermostat?  What about the water temp sensor?  The fuse that was replaced, what was it for?  Look up the info as Paulster said.

Answer (score 0):

Battery and Brake Light on simultaneously on most Japanese vehicles generally means a bad alternator. I owned a 2003 Galant with the same engine and had the same issue.

Most Retail Automotive Parts Stores will provide a charging system test for free.

The Gauges indicating improperly are likely a separate issue. Gauges malfunctioning and blown fuses would lead me to worry about electrical health. I would start by removing the electrical grounds, cleaning, and reattaching them.

As another user mentioned, make sure that you have the proper level of coolant, and that it's circulating properly. Bring the vehicle up to operating temperature and check the temperature of both the upper and lower radiator hose, either with a non-contact Infrared Thermometer or by feeling the hose with your hand (exercise caution for moving options excessive heat etc.)

[Here is an article at YourMechanic.com which gets into How to Diagnose Cooling Issues](https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/how-to-diagnose-a-cooling-system-problem-by-tyler-kirkland) If you do have an issue where both hoses never get warm, even after the vehicle is at operating temperature, then you should continue with some of the other components covered in that article linked.

I hope this helps.